# Having trouble understanding Model and Controller in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

The more post I read the more confused I got....

In spring MVC:

What I got was this. View is just your jsp. Dispatcher Servlet is your controller. It handles the request and direct to appropriate actions. Then @Controller (some class) is also your controller but under the same class (from tutorials point) you can have @modelattribute which is your model object. First, I thought the purpose is to separate model and controller (that's why we use MVC) so why is your business logic can be the same class as your controller? So what exactly is Model and Controller in Spring? can you have two controllers? (@Controller class and dispatcher servlet) Models in spring are from @modelattribute objects or the beans from business logic?

Comment: No, it's because *your question* is confused. Don't pout. Read this instead: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Views are not just JSP, but any view technology, such as JasperReports

> I thought the purpose is to separate model and controller (that's why
>   we use MVC) so why is your business logic can be the same class as
>   your controller?

You business logic should go in service classes, which are referenced by controllers. You can put some simple validation in entities themselves.

> So what exactly is Model and Controller in Spring?

Model is a map of any data that your view might need. It can contain Entities, or Form Backing Objects or Strings or anything you want.

DispatcherServlet is your *front* controller, not your regular controller.

Controller is a class with Handler Methods that are called due to HTTP requests, and generally collect model data and pass them to a view.

> can you have two controllers? (@Controller class and dispatcher
>   servlet)

You can have as many controller as you want. The more the merrier! Generally one front controller is enough.

> Models in spring are from @modelattribute objects or the beans from
>   business logic?

`@ModelAttribute` is a special, ill-documented, poorly-understood annotation that shouldn't worry about until you understand the basics.

Model is a map of anything you want. It is all of the data that the view needs to do its view thing.